# Debugging multi-stage build using docker-compose in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose, dockerfile, visual-studio-2022

I recently update my application to .net 6 so I had to move to VS2022.
I've also converted all my dockerfiles in the projects to multi-stage build.
When trying to debug the application using the docker-compose I'm getting the exception:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm7BL.png)

Information on VS2022:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.3.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.3.6+32929.385
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA743
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.3.376.3011
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.3.376.3011
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.3.376.3011
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   4.3.0-3.22470.13+80a8ce8d5fdb9ceda4101e2acb8e8eb7be4ebcea
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet Package Manager   6.3.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2232702+e1d654e792aa2fe6646a6935bcca80ff0aff4387
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62207.04100
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

TypeScript Tools   17.0.10701.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.3.0-3.22470.13+80a8ce8d5fdb9ceda4101e2acb8e8eb7be4ebcea
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.22363.4+1b94f89d4d1f41f20f9be73c76f4b229d4e49078
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.
```

Couldn't find any information about this exception